# Trying to write a basic bash script, but failing to do a keystroke space

Tags: bash, macos

I would like to write a script that opens a Youtube song and "presses" the spacebar to play the song. I've spent quite a lot of time trying to fix that last bit, "pressing" the spacebar. I'm trying to get this to work on my Mac.

Here's the script

```
#!/bin/bash
open https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG6o_C9SOW8&list=LL&index=10&ab_channel=mick73funk
sleep 5s
#printf "0x20"
keystroke space
```

It opens the tab with the song in Firefox, so far so good. But then gives an error

```
$ ./finally_friday.sh 
./finally_friday.sh: line 9: keystroke: command not found
```

I tried `printf "0x20"` before and different variants of `[SPACE]` like `{SPACE}` but it always comes back with "command not found".

Update, 17 april: I kind of got it working with Apple script(thank you Mr R). If I execute it from the Terminal the space key is pressed in the Terminal and not in Firefox. But if I schedule the script in crontab it works as expected.

```
osascript << EOF

tell application "Firefox"
    open location "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG6o_C9SOW8&list=LL&index=10&ab_channel=mick73funk"
    delay 4
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke space
    end tell
end tell
EOF
```

A friend of mine solved the task with Python, here is his code that works executing it from the Terminal as well.

```
import os
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

path = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG6o_C9SOW8&list=LL&index=10&ab_channel=mick73funk "
os.system(f"open {path}")

time.sleep(5)
# Press and release space
keyboard.press(Key.space)
keyboard.release(Key.space)
```

A big thank you to all that has replied to my post!

Comment: Where did you think the keystroke command would be coming from? Does that work *outside* your script?

Comment: Because it's on a mac you might be able to use applescript to send a key event to firefox.  See `man osascript` then something like `tell application "System Events"
 tell application "Firefox" to activate
 keystroke " "` ..  found this https://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/keycodes.php and https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes
end tell

Comment: You are right, "keystroke space" does not work in the terminal so I cannot expect it to work in my script.

Comment: Thank you Mr R! That looks promising, I'll check it out tomorrow.

Comment: This doesn't answer the exact question you asked but another possibility to get the same effect is to play the video in something other than firefox such as the video player mpv. In this case it would be a simple as running `mpv youtube.com/example`. This also bypasses the potential issue that some videos require you to sign in before it will play.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the onliner that worked for me in kali-Linux should work in your system too

```
firefox https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fG6o_C9SOW8&list=LL&index=10&ab_channel=mick73funk ; sleep 5s ; xdotool key space
```

Make sure you have installed xdotool before running

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```